# flask-bootstrap utils icon increase glyphs size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, flask, flask-bootstrap

I'm using `Flask-Bootstrap`

```
$ pip show flask_bootstrap
Name: Flask-Bootstrap
Version: 3.3.7.1
```

I use `utils.icon` to get glyphs:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/utils.html" as utils %}

{% block content %}
  {{ utils.icon("pencil") }}
{% endblock %}
```

Following [documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/macros.html#utilities) I don't succeed to increase the glyphs size

Comment: _"these are intended to aid rapid application development, until they are replaced with custom solutions in more mature applications"_ so just use the normal boostrap method: `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>` and you can apply styling to it with css

Answer (score 0):

`icon()` macro takes another parameter named `extra_classes` so you specify your css class for the size of icon:

```
{{ utils.icon("pencil", ["large"]) }}

<style type="text/css">
    .large { font-size: 50px; }
</style>
```